# Changing the mouse pointer in Mate

Tags: x11, mate-desktop

I am using Fedora 20 with the Mate desktop. I sometimes give talks, using LibreOffice Impress for a slide show, with a laser to point out details on the screen. I will be giving a talk where the slides are displayed on a TV screen, which is non-reflective so the little red spot does not show. The mouse pointer is an obvious substitute, but the arrow icon does not show up very well.  Is there a way of using a different, more visible icon, say one that I can choose from a set provided, or that I can design for myself?

---

I see my question has been edited, but I'm not sure it was needed or that it is now an improvement on what I wrote originally. Especially the comma after "more visible", that has changed the sense of it, and I particularly do not like to see the "Please" deleted, I like to be polite.

---

I have followed switch87 suggestions and downloaded a new theme, which is now installed thanks to his help. I very much appreciate his patient help.

Comment: Have you looked in the settings? You should be able to change the cursor in Appearance  -> Customize -> Cursors.

Comment: Thanks terdon, but that offers only two choices, the default white arrow with black outline, or black with white outline, both a bit too small really.

Comment: You do not have to unzip/untar, the zioped file is the installation file.

Comment: Thanks again switch87, worked instantly and brilliantly, but now please, for my curiosity, how did you discover that, i.e. that unzipping etc not needed? -- it is so counter-intuitive that I would never have thought of even looking at that as a possibility.

Comment: just by trying I suppose... It's to long ago I did this for the first time - I think 9 or 10 years ago - so I don't remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mate uses themes and mouse pointers of gnome2 (gtk2 actually), so a good place to start looking is [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/?xcontentmode=36) , here you can find many themes for the mouse pointer to install, and it works, I use mate myself.

After downloading the theme file (do not extract it!) go to the **appearance** screen of gnome or mate, there you have a **install** button, use it to install the downloaded theme. afterward you can go to **customize** to change it.

Comment: Thanks switch87, that is very good, looks like exactly what I want, so I will mark that as answered, but it would be useful if you could kindly explain a little bit more. Later today I will put the details of where I have got to, in an edit to my question.